# Add list item only after workflow approval

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, client-object-model, custom-list, list-item

Is there a way to restrict or hold the list item from adding into the list until it is approved? Once the user hits the save button from new user form, the workflow approval request starts and until it is approved, the new list item must not be added to the list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can enable content approval from List Settings.

This will ensure the items get saved as drafts and other users will not see it until its approved.

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08

Comment: Thanks @Amal. Yes the content approval is an option. But it applies for all the forms. I need it to be done only to my custom form. Is there any other option?

Comment: You mean you have multiple content types associated with the list and you want content approval for a particular content type? can you please elaborate what you mean by only to my custom form?

Comment: I have two forms in my list. one is normal add item form and the other merges the selected items and adds to the list (call this as merge form). And I have a check box for publish in the merge form. When the user checks the publish button and saves the form, the workflow must be initiated and that item must not be posted until it is approved. Is this clear enough?

Comment: Ok in that case you need to modify the view so it filters our not approved items. Then use either out of the box approval workflow or make one using Designer. Once approved you should fill the data in such a way that it get displayed in the View.

Comment: Is there a way to add a workflow only to particular items?

Comment: You can add the workflow to run on new item created. This will automatically run whenever a new item is added to the list.

Comment: I want the workflow to be started only when user clicks the publish button or else normal insert.

Comment: Ok you can still start the workflow on new item created. Inside the workflow you can check if publish button is pressed (for example on publish click you can put a value in a hidden field [Pubished] = 'Yes'

Comment: I'm not able to set the approver, when I create a workflow using designer. And when I create a workflow using browser, I'm not able to set the if publish condition.

Comment: Have you add a hidden field say with name Published? Have you updated your form to put value say 'Yes' into that field on Publish button click? Once the above two are done, inside the workflow you can add a condition "If currentitem:Published eq 'Yes'" then start the approval process.

Comment: yes I did the above steps. But how to set the content approver (user to approve the content).

Comment: One SPD workflow you can add the approval process and choose the approver. https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/sharepoint-custom-approval-workflow-with-dynamic-approvers-using-sharepoint-designer/